# VueJS: Forms in v-for - How to get the correct data?

Tags: loops, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

So in a table I'm displaying multiple "Reservations" using Vue.js & `v-for`.

Each row in the table has a form which consists of this:

```
<tr v-for="reservation in reservations" :key="reservation.id">
            <td>
                <form @submit.prevent="sendAnswer" method="post" >
                    <select name="reservationResponse" id="reservationResponse" v-model="selected">
                        <option value="invalid">-- Select Answer --</option>
                        <option value="confirm">Confirm</option>
                        <option value="full">Full</option>
                        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
                        <option value="remove">Remove without E-Mail</option>
                    </select>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" value="Send answer">
                </form>
            </td>
</tr>
```

Now, when I press one of the submit buttons how can I get the correct reservation associated with the form from my `reservations` array?

e.g.: I want to send a post request updating the status of the respective reservation. Therefor, I need the id and the option value of the selected reservation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, you need to apply a `v-model` to  your `select` so that you can read the data. Create a variable in `data()` (such as `reservationResponseSelection` in this example), and then on the `select` itself add `v-model="reservationResponseSelection"`. The variable will be [reactive][1], and update when you select a new option. You can then read that data in your `sendAnswer` method.

---

As you are using a `v-for` to generate this data, you will need create a unique variable for each `select`. You can do this by using the unique data that is passed into the loop. For example you could use the `reservation.id` (the same one that you're using for the `:key`).

In your `data()` you would do:

````
data() {
  reservationOptions: {}
},```

and then on your `select` you would add: `v-model="reservationOptions[reservation.id]"`

This then gives you an object with your reservation values corresponding to each ID inside it.


  [1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html
````